# Como enviar imagens e campos de texto para api em nodejs com react-native

Tags: node.js, react, react-native, express.js, multer

Galera, estou tentando enviar um array de imagens e campos em texto para minha API feita em NodeJs com Express, porem não estou conseguindo.

Estou recebendo todas as informações no body da requisição, e meu multer la na API pega as imagens do req.files.

A dúvida é a seguinte, consigo separar essas informações? Mandar o array de imagens para o req.files e os campos de texto para o req.body...

Abaixo é como estou enviando..

```
const formData = new FormData();

    for (const image of arrayImages) {
      formData.append("fileData", image.path);
    }

formData.append("user_id", user.uid);
formData.append("user_name", user.displayName);

axios
  .post("http://localhost:3000/adverts", formData, {
      headers: {
        ...formData.get,
      },
    })
    .then(() => {
      Alert.alert("Anúncio cadastrado com sucesso");
      handleReset();
      navigation.navigate("MyAds");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

e aqui o que estou recebendo

```
body: [Object: null prototype] {
    fileData: '/Users/lucascamargo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/13C95366-4C85-434D-8A8C-11C9DC82A407/data/Containers/Data/Application/B5D392B3-A528-4A65-A5FB-D7D5D61CDA16/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/9FC89160-1CC9-4F8C-8079-1C15ABA8871E.jpg',
    user_id: 'nIGIpK4BS7MS4383oK6ZxhvPN2v1',
    user_name: 'paola@paola.com',
  },
  route: Route {
    path: '/adverts',
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
    methods: { post: true }
  },
  files: [],
```

Answer (score -3):

Por padrão seuas imagens estarão disponíveis em `req.files` no seu backend.

> Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form.
> Referência: [Multer Middleware Express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html#usage)

O que acontece, é que o que você está subindo não são imagens, somente um URL de onde elas estão no seu computador. Em outras palavras você está subindo apenas um texto, por isso não cai em `req.files`:

Para que isso seja possivel tu precisa passar para o `FormData`, o atributo do seu input onde contém as informações da imagem ou imagems (mais a frente explico o porque imagem ou imagens);

Toda vez que tu precisar fazer o upload de qualquer aquivos, independente do formato, tu usa a tag `input` sendo seu tipo igual a `file`.

Exemplo: `<input type="file" />`

E para poder pegar os bytes dos arquivos que serão carregado nessa `input` tu chama a propriedade `files`.

Exemplo:

```
const Input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
console.log(Input.files)
```

## Um código prático

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]")

const Button = document.querySelector("#BtnEnviar");

function upload(payload) {
  fetch('https://example.com/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: payload
  })
  .then(() => { /* caso sucesso */ })
  .catch(() => { /* caso falha */ })
}

Button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   const formData = new FormData();
  
   Array.from(inputs).forEach((Input) => {
        const name = Input.files[0].name;
        formData.append(name, Input.files[0]);
  });

  upload(payload)
})
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" >
  <input type="file" >
  <input type="file" >

  <button type"submit" id="BtnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

## Multiplos arquivos com uma input

Como você pode ver acima. o atributo `files` é um array. Isso porque uma mesma `input` pode acomodar 1 arquivo, ou multiplos. basta setar o atributo `multiple` para a tag HTML

Exemplo `<input type="file" multiple>`

Ao fazer isso, quando a jenla do gerenciador de arquivos abrir, o usuário pode fazer uma seleção multipla dos arquivos desejados.

```js
const Button = document.querySelector("#BtnEnviar");
const Input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");

function upload(payload) {
  fetch('https://example.com/upload', {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: payload
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((error) => {/* erro */});
}

Button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  
  // Envia no padrão multi-value fields
  [...Input.files].forEach((file) => {
    formData.append("image[]", file);
  })

  // Ou no padrão do exemplo anterio usando nome do arquivo
  //[...Input.files].forEach((file) => {
  //  formData.append(file.name, file);
  //})

  upload(formData)
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" multiple />
  <button type="button" id="BtnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

## Coleções de elemento HTML

Quero só chamar a atenção para um ponto importante sobre "Arrays" de elemetos HTML. Eles não são as mesma coisa que Arrays do Javascript

Veja [HTMLCollection MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) e [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). São respectivamente as interface de retornadas quando se usa o `querySelectorAll()` ou quando se manipula o atributo `files` da `input`.

Então para poder interar sobre cada um dos itens nessas coleções eu faço uma converção para `Array` do JS. Tanto `[...Coleção]` quanto `Array.from(Coleção)` fazem exatamente a mesma coisa.

Mais informações sobre `<input type="file"/>` veja [Input file MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)
Mais informaçoes sobre `new FormData` [FormData MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#retrieving_a_formdata_object_from_an_html_form)

Mais links que podem ajudar a enteder como upload de arquivos funcionam:
[Como funciona o upload de arquivos HTTP? (Em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)
[Content-Type Multipart (Em inglês)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)
[Como o FormData gera o payload (Em inglês)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Comment: O pessoal negativa a pergunta e as respostas, mas não se dão ao trabalho de comentar o porque negativaram. Vai entender....

Comment: OBS: Ninguém é pago para responder aqui no fórum. Então favor, se negativar uma pergunta ou resposta pelo menos se deem o trabalho de comentar o porque.
Pois nos damos ao trabalho de tentar ajudar.

Answer (score -4):

Fala mano, boa tarde, pelo que estou vendo, nesse seu for você está sobrescrevendo o file toda vez que você roda ele, o que pode funcionar é você é você criar um array temporário e rodar um esse seu for incluindo todos os files nele, e ai quando você for atribuiuir o valor no formData, você atribui ele, tipo assim:

```
let array = []
for(let i = 0; i<arrayImages.length;i++){
    array.push(image.path);
}
formData.append("fileData", array );
```

Algo nesse caminho, entendeu?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porem eu achei o problema. Eu nao estava passando um objeto no meu append.. Ex: formData.append("fileData", { uri: image.path, type: "image/jpg", filename: "teste.png" })